# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser [fatal error Call to a member function find() on a non-object ]

Tags: php, html, dom, get

Anyone knows why I have this error? What am I doing wrong?

```
<?
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = ("http://99designs.pt/logo-design/contests?show=finished");
foreach($html->find('span[class=active.sl_notranslate]') as $aholder) {

echo $aholder . '<br>';
}
?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   ../simplehtml.php on line 5

Comment: In this instance `$html` is a string so it won't have any methods attached to it.

Comment: thanks, It was missing this: `$html = file_get_html($url);`

Do you know how I echo the "span" content?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the function name `file_get_html`, the code should be like this:

```
<?php
  include 'simple_html_dom.php';

  $html = file_get_html("http://99designs.pt/logo-design/contests?show=finished");
  foreach($html->find('span[class=active.sl_notranslate]') as $aholder) {

    echo $aholder . '<br>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: To echo the span content you should put this code inside the foreach `echo $aholder->innertext . '<br>';`

Check the documentation here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, it is very well exaplined.

Comment: I add that, but is returning nothing... The content of the span is from the data base of the website. Is that the problem?

On console I have this error: "GET http://js.bizographics.com/insight.min.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT "

Comment: no, the console doesn`t have anything with this. i checked the source of the url which you provided but there is no span with  .sl_notranslate class.

Comment: you are right. It's not "active.sl_notranslate". It's "active sl_notranslate". I got it, thanks :)